# How to identify chosen radio button value React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I would like the console to print a unique text for the different radio buttons. For example if the user chooses the radio button valued label1, the console should print 'You chose label1'. The file contains three radio buttons and their values that are from a different file. I save the users choice in a asyncstorage, when the button is pressed. This is my file:

```
import RadioButtonRN from 'radio-buttons-react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {Questions} from '../questions/questions_user'

export const ScreenOne = ({ }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const question3 = Questions[2].question;
  const label1 = Questions[2].answers[0].answer;
  const label2 = Questions[2].answers[1].answer;
  const label3 = Questions[2].answers[2].answer;

  const [radioBtn, setSelectedRadioBtn] = useState('')

  const saveValue = () => {
    if (radioBtn) {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('radioValue', JSON.stringify(radioBtn))
      setSelectedRadioBtn('');
    } 
  }

  const data = [
    {
      label: label1
    },
    {
      label: label2
    },
    {
      label: label3
    }
  ];

  return (
    <ScreenContainer>
        <RadioButtonRN
          data={data}
          selectedBtn={(e) => setSelectedRadioBtn(e)}
          box={false}
          circleSize={14}
          activeColor={'#6175CF'}
          style={styles.radio}
        />
      </InputArea>
          <Button onPress={saveValue} />
    </ScreenContainer>
  )
}

export default ScreenOne
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {Questions} from '../questions/questions_user'

export const ScreenOne = ({ }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const question3 = Questions[2].question;
  const label1 = Questions[2].answers[0].answer;
  const label2 = Questions[2].answers[1].answer;
  const label3 = Questions[2].answers[2].answer;

  const [radioBtn, setSelectedRadioBtn] = useState('')

  const saveValue = () => {
    if (radioBtn) {
      AsyncStorage.setItem('radioValue', JSON.stringify(radioBtn))
      setSelectedRadioBtn('');
    } 
  }

  const data = [
    {
      label: label1
    },
    {
      label: label2
    },
    {
      label: label3
    }
  ];

  return (
    <ScreenContainer>
        <RadioButtonRN
          data={data}
          selectedBtn={(e) => setSelectedRadioBtn(e)}
          box={false}
          circleSize={14}
          activeColor={'#6175CF'}
          style={styles.radio}
        />
      </InputArea>
          <Button onPress={saveValue} />

       <Text>{radioBtn.label}</Text>

    </ScreenContainer>
  )
}

export default ScreenOne;
```

Comment: @edwin you can access the label using radioBtn.label. Hope that helps!